# Replace :hasName with rdfs:label in RDF

Tags: sparql, rdf, sesame, rdfs

In my graph I have these triples:

```
:Pieta              :hasName "Pieta".
:David              :hasName "David".
:MasaTacerii        :hasName "Masa Tacerii".
:USA                :hasName "United States of America"@en, "Etats Unis d'Amerique"@fr.
```

I want to replace :hasName with rdfs:label .
Can I do that using sameAs property ?Or do I have another possibility?

Answer (score 3):

`owl:sameAs` would create a statement about your RDF resource.  But by itself it is completely inert.  If executed with a standard OWL reasoner, it will create the triples that make each resource in the subject and object of the `owl:sameAs` have the same property values.  OWL reasoning is not a general processing system, it is a type of FOPL that is monotonic (i.e. facts can be inserted and inferred, but not retracted).

However, the operation you want has a straightforward implementation in SPARQL:

```
DELETE {
   ?s :hasName ?o .
}
INSERT {
   ?s rdfs:label ?o .
}
WHERE {
   ?s :hasName ?o .
}
```

Basically, find all of the `:hasName` properties, delete them and add `rdfs:label` instead.